# Use a LAN IP for dnsmasq

Tags: mac-osx, vagrant, dnsmasq

We have a single iMac in our office running a Vagrant box exposing the public IP of 192.168.1.70. Everyone in the office used to all be able to access sites on this box (which all use ".dev" such as http://domain.dev) using dnsmasq with the following settings in `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
address=/.dev/192.168.1.70
```

Since we all updated to OSX Mavericks we've not been able to get this to work. I've looked through various walkthroughs on getting dnsmasq working ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579138/osx-mavericks-dnsmasq-stops-working) and [this](http://blakeembrey.com/articles/local-development-with-dnsmasq/)) but they all rely on a localhost IP. One step suggested in various places is the addition of a dev entry within `/etc/resolver` so I created `/etc/resolver/dev` with this content:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.70
```

However we're still not able to access sites using .dev. We can access them using 192.168.1.70 though.

Any ideas?

In answer to a question in the comments, when I `dig domain.dev @127.0.0.1` I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> domain.dev @127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17610
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.dev.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.dev.     0   IN  A   192.168.1.70

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Mar 19 09:04:40 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
```

but when I go to domain.dev (where domain.dev is a site set up on the server) in chrome I just get `This webpage is not available`

Thanks.

Comment: So what happens if you try to `dig domain.dev @127.0.0.1`?  What error do you get when you try to access the .dev sites?

Comment: thanks for your reply - I added more detail to the question

Comment: What was updated to Makericks, how does it 'not work' - what error messages are you seeing and where are you seeing them ?

Comment: Literally just no longer able to access sites using `.dev` - the domains no longer resolving correctly to the vagrant box

Comment: Are you sure your office computers are using the correct nameserver?  Dnsmasq appears to be responding with what you'd expect.

Comment: not sure - if you see my answer below that might highlight something obvious to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by changing `/etc/resolver/dev` to

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I'm not sure entirely which this works or why the other version didn't.